# Create Approval Process on Account Team

Tags: account, approval-process, account-teams

Is there anyway to create an approval process on Account Team. So that the account team members will be requested through an approval process and their mangers can approve them so that they can be added in Account Team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build a custom solution for this use case.

Create a separate object like `Account Team Management` which will have related object like `Account Team Members` which will have user Id.

Expose `Account Team Management` as a Tab and define approval process on this object.

After approval, you need to write a trigger to add users to the Account Team.